# How to pass arguments to bash shell script when executing that command with at?

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, at

I have a shell script that accepts an argument and uses that in the script. So to run the script I type 
`/path/to/script argument`

The problem is when trying to setup that file to run using the `at` utility. I have tried

`at -f /path/to/script argument 17:45`

`at -f '/path/to/script argument' 17:45`

but neither of these options work. First one receives a syntax error and the second says no such file Any suggestions?

Comment: Just put `/path/to/script argument` in another script, and call that script instead.

Comment: That pretty much defeats the purpose of having arguments in the shell script. Thanks though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `at` defaults to reading from standard input, you can just do this:

```
echo /path/to/script argument | at 17:45
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend following the advice of @warl0ck in the general case -- create a new script, e.g. `/path/to/newscript`:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 /path/to/script argument
```

and then run that using `at`:

```
 at -f /path/to/newscript 17:45
```

This makes it easy to adjust whatever arguments are needed, run multiple commands, etc.

Alternatively, for occasional or one-off use, you can just run `at` with the chosen time, and then enter whatever command(s) you need on standard input; hit `ctrl-D` to end:

```
 myhost# at 17:45
 /path/to/script argument
 <ctrl-D>
 Job 1 will be executed using /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too and I solved it by using EOF.

This is starting a `ssh` connection to `sshserverhost` that executes `test.sh` with parameter `$HOSTNAME` on the remote server (sshserverhost).

```sh
at now + 1 minutes <<EOF
ssh -t sshserverhost 'bash -s' <~/test.sh $HOSTNAME
EOF
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the OP's question, or are you saying you have the issue too...